# placesClient - properly use sharedClient method?

Tags: swift, callback, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

placesClient gives an error of holding a nil value, after reading through the google places documentation I read this statement:

> This class should be accessed through the [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient] method.

I am wondering how to implement the sharedClient method in order to run a search based on the placesID for the information on the given place?

```
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

func lookUpPlaceID() {
    let placeID = "ChIJPXw5JDZM6IAR4rTXaFQDGys"

    //What value should placesClient be holding if not GMSPlacesClient in order to run the search based on the placeID?

    self.placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(placeID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
            print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let place = place {
            print("Place name \(place.name)")
            print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
            print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
        } else {
            print("No place details for \(placeID)")
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: whoops. updated the code to what i actually have. what could possibly be incorrect? thanks

Comment: `placesClient` (declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional) is nil, not `placeID`.

Comment: woah, thats interesting. But now I'm definitely lost on what is supposed to be done in order to acquire the information through the google places api. :(

Comment: my first real app process. but still don't really get what value placesClient is supposed to be assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sharedClient` is class method in Objective C.  In Swift you treat it like a [Type Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html).  So instead of assigning `placesClient` to the `GMSPlacesClient` type, assign it to the result of the `sharedClient` type method:

```
let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()
```

`placesClient` will now hold an **instance** of `GMSPlacesClient` (a shared instance, later calls to `sharedClient` will return the same instance if it hasn't been garbage collected), rather than holding the **type** as your original code did.

Comment: ahh I appreciate it greatly! but when i try it with that code i get an error as well. Xcode wants a semicolon in-between the parenthesis and shared client? Will the class need to inherit any certain class or any delegate protocols?

Comment: Oops, yes, a typo.  (Sorry, my Swift is a bit rusty).  `let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedInstance` should work I think.  (`let` rather than `var` as you're not going to need/want to reassign it most likely).

Comment: sharedClient() ///reportDeviceAtPlaceWithID(placeID: String)/// lookUpPlaceID()/// currentPlaceWithCallback() ///autocompleteQuery/// addPlace()
Above are the methods of GMSPlacesClient
Been trying to work with it but sharedInstance isn't one of the methods within the GMSPlacesClient Class and gives error "Type GMSPlacesClient has no member "sharedInstance". I feel like we are really close to figuring this out haha

Comment: Oops, I meant `let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()` (which is how I edited my answer!).  Sorry for the repeated typos :(

Comment: Yup, your code works perfect, but in the app delegate I get a sigabrt error. A little more debugging for me to go!

Comment: Make sure you initialize your places client **after** the view has loaded, otherwise you will get an `provideAPIKey` error: `Google Places API for iOS must be initialized via [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:...] prior to use`.